# How to make newly created user as sudo user by using chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have created a user 'testuser' by using chef.  How to make this user as sudo user?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Try searching sudo in http://supermarket.chef.io ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to modify sudo group by using `group` resource:

```
group "create testuser sudo" do
  group_name 'sudo'
  members 'testuser'
  action :modify
  append true
end
```

Another way is to use sudo recipe https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo .

Recommended way to me is to go with the sudo recipe and offload system specific logic to recipe. There you get attributes resource configurations that makes you recipe code robust.

Comment: Thanks for your Ans. I have tested this and it worked for me:-)

Answer (score 3):

There's an existing [sudo cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo) for managing this.

There's a `sudo` LWRP that will then allow you to add a user (it will add file to the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory)

```
sudo 'tomcat' do
  user      "%tomcat"    # or a username
  runas     'app_user'   # or 'app_user:tomcat'
  commands  ['/etc/init.d/tomcat restart']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You do it the same way as always, by adding the user to your `/etc/sudoers` config. You could manage that file using a `template` resource, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chef 14, 'sudo' is a resource